# If else statement in ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, if-statement

I have created a actionscript with Capabilities function It works good, but I want to ad a If else statement on the capabilities for language.

I'm running in English so the capabilities shows " EN ", but I want the if else statement to change " EN " to = English, and if we are running in different language it would say " Other language"

This is what i have at the moment.

```
var versionString = Capabilities.language;

var label2:TextField = createCustomTextField(0, 60, 200, 20);
label2.text = "language: " + Capabilities.language;
```

Any ideas how to use the if and else statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
label2.text = "language: " + (Capabilities.language.toLowerCase() == "en" ? "English" : "Other");
```

or the normal if statement way:

```
if(Capabilities.language.toLowerCase() == "en"){
    label2.text = "language: English";
} else {
    label2.text = "language: Other";
}
```

Comment: Perfect, This was just was I was looking for. How did you come up with the toLowerCase() == " en") ?

Thank you

Comment: toLowerCase() is a function of the String class, you can use it on any String, such as Capabilities.language.